# -split function doesn't work in a big file Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, split

I'm trying to use Powershell to parse a csv file, but split function doesn't work. I'm comparing file output using split and raw line. Split only works for the first few rows. I don't know if I'm missing something. Here is my code

```
$table = Get-Content .\random.csv -ReadCount 1000

$fname_mid = 'ps.mid'
$fname_mif = 'ps.mif'

New-Item -Path . -Name $fname_mid -ItemType 'file' -Force
New-Item -Path . -Name $fname_mif -ItemType 'file' -Force

ForEach($_ In $table) 
{
    $read_field = $_ -split ','
    $read_line = '----' + $read_field[0] + ',-' + $read_field[9] + '-'

    $read_line | Out-File -Encoding 'UTF8' -FilePath $fname_mid -Append
    $_ | Out-File -Encoding 'UTF8' -FilePath $fname_mif -Append
}
```

File for testing https://www.dropbox.com/s/99zgerh2akemgy3/random.csv?dl=0

Comment: this >>> `ForEach($_ In $table)` <<< really otta trigger an error. the `$_` variable is the **_current pipeline item_** ... and you are not using the pipeline. replace it with a proper current item variable [perhaps `$T_Item`] and see what happens.

Comment: `-ReadCount` _Specifies how many **lines** of content are sent through the pipeline at a time_.  Hence, `$Table.Count` => 40 and`$Table[0].Gettype()` => `Object[]` and  `($Table[0]  -split [System.Environment]::NewLine).Count` => 1000  and  `($Table[-1]  -split [System.Environment]::NewLine).Count` => 233.

Comment: Why aren't you using Import-csv?  If it's an ordinary csv,  this will be the easy way.

Comment: @WalterMitty Because it's very slow when file sizes is greater 10MB

Comment: It works a little faster when you feed its output through a pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken issues in your question (also listed by the comments) in account:

- From [@Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey):
  this >>> `ForEach($_ In $table)` <<< really otta trigger an error. the $_ variable is the ***current pipeline item*** ... and you are not using the pipeline. replace it with a proper current item variable [perhaps `$T_Item`] and see what happens.
- From [@JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz):
  `-ReadCount` Specifies how many lines of content are sent through the pipeline at a time. Hence,
  `$Table.Count` => 40 and `$Table[0].Gettype()` => `Object[]` and
  `($Table[0] -split [System.Environment]::NewLine).Count` => 1000 and
  `($Table[-1] -split [System.Environment]::NewLine).Count` => 233
- You have **9** columns in the provided example, which means that the last item is
  **`$read_field[8]`** (**`8`** not **`9`**)
- This statement, `$_ | Out-File -Encoding 'UTF8' -FilePath $fname_mif -Append` doesn't do much (unless your source isn't `UTF8`, but then there are other ways to accomplish the same)
- How do you want to handle the quotes in the input file?

You will get something like:

```
$table = Get-Content .\random.csv

$fname_mid = 'ps.mid'
$fname_mif = 'ps.mif'

New-Item -Path . -Name $fname_mid -ItemType 'file' -Force
New-Item -Path . -Name $fname_mif -ItemType 'file' -Force

ForEach($Line In $table) 
{
    $read_field = $Line -split ','
    $read_line = '----' + $read_field[0] + ',-' + $read_field[8] + '-'

    $read_line | Out-File -Encoding 'UTF8' -FilePath $fname_mid -Append
    # $Line | Out-File -Encoding 'UTF8' -FilePath $fname_mif -Append
}
```

But you are underestimating the performance (and the ease of use) of [`Import-csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) (as commented by [@Walter Mitty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19937/walter-mitty)) and the sophisticated PowerShell pipeline that comes with it. The point is that you can't just base your **performance measurements on a single command** if you want to compare it with cmdlets that are built for streaming. In such a case, you will need to **measure the full solution**.

Where your (corrected) example takes more than **7 minutes**,
streaming will take a less than **3 seconds**:

```
Import-Csv .\random.csv -Head (0..8) | 
ForEach-Object {"----$($_.0),-$($_.8)-"} | 
Set-Content .\fname_mid
```

Comment: Thanks for referencing my comment in your answer.  I thought this was the way to go, but I was too lazy to build an answer that uses import-csv.

Comment: I'm new in Powershell, it helped me to understand how PS works, Thanks.